# Change View Layout on Keyboard Notifications (Swift, iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am attempting to create an login screen for an iOS app, using Swift.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkJIj.png) is what I want it to look like without the keyboard hidden. Once the user taps a textfield, I'd like to change to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnLjO.png), with the keyboard shown. As you can see, it is more compact

I have tried to do it on my own, but cannot seem to figure it out using the examples I've found online, since I am using `AutoLayoutConstraints` in `InterfaceBuilder`. Everything is embedded into a `UIScrollView`.

My question is, am I doing this correctly? As in, removing all constraints previously set in `InterfaceBuilder` and then redoing them programmatically to make it look like I want.

Is there a better way to do this? This seems tedious. I am new to Swift/iOS programming, so my apologies if this is an obvious question.

Here is what I have done, so far:

---

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var logoText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var forgotPasswordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var createAccountButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}
```

---

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
        let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeShown:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

---

```
func keyboardWillBeShown(sender: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().height

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds           // get screen size
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width                              // ... screen width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height                            // ... screen height
    let heightToFit = screenHeight - keyboardHeight                 // ... height of screen with keyboard

    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.removeConstraints(self.view.constraints)

    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                  attribute: .Bottom,
                  relatedBy: .Equal,
                     toItem: self.view,
                  attribute: .Bottom,
                 multiplier: 1.0,
                   constant: -keyboardHeight ))

    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                  attribute: .Top,
                  relatedBy: .Equal,
                     toItem: self.view,
                  attribute: .Top,
                 multiplier: 1.0,
                   constant: 0.0))


    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                  attribute: .Trailing,
                  relatedBy: .Equal,
                     toItem: self.view,
                  attribute: .Trailing,
                 multiplier: 1.0,
                   constant: 0.0))

    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                  attribute: .Leading,
                  relatedBy: .Equal,
                     toItem: self.view,
                  attribute: .Leading,
                 multiplier: 1.0,
                   constant: 0.0))

    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                  attribute: .Height,
                  relatedBy: .Equal,
                     toItem: nil,
                  attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                 multiplier: 1.0,
                   constant: heightToFit))

    self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
                  attribute: .Width,
                  relatedBy: .Equal,
                     toItem: nil,
                  attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                 multiplier: 1.0,
                   constant: screenWidth))


    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, self.usernameTextField.frame.origin.y - 50), animated: true)
}
```

---

```
func keyboardWillBeHidden(sender: NSNotification) {
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds           // get screen size
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width                              // ... screen width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height                            // ... screen height

        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

        self.view.removeConstraints(self.view.constraints)

        self.view.addConstraint(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                          attribute: .Bottom,
                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                             toItem: self.view,
                          attribute: .Bottom,
                         multiplier: 1.0,
                           constant: screenHeight ))

        self.view.addConstraint(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                          attribute: .Top,
                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                             toItem: self.view,
                          attribute: .Top,
                        multiplier: 1.0,
                          constant: 0.0))

        self.view.addConstraint(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                          attribute: .Trailing,
                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                             toItem: self.view,
                          attribute: .Trailing,
                         multiplier: 1.0,
                           constant: 0.0))

        self.view.addConstraint(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                          attribute: .Leading,
                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                             toItem: self.view,
                          attribute: .Leading,
                         multiplier: 1.0,
                           constant: 0.0))

        self.view.addConstraint(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView,
                          attribute: .Height,
                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                             toItem: nil,
                          attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                        multiplier: 1.0,
                          constant: screenHeight))

        self.view.addConstraint(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
                          attribute: .Width,
                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                             toItem: nil,
                          attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                         multiplier: 1.0,
                           constant: screenWidth))


  self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -self.usernameTextField.frame.origin.y + 50), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: What is your deployment target? iOS 9, or something earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not get it to work with the `AutoLayoutConstraints`, so I disabled it and did all the math myself.

Here's a small snippet:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds           // get screen size
let screenWidth = screenSize.width                              // ... screen width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height                            // ... screen height
let padding: CGFloat = 30                                       // space on left and right
let adjustedViewWidth = screenWidth - 2*padding

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

self.logoImage.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - self.logoImage.frame.width/2, self.logoImage.frame.origin.y, self.logoImage.frame.width, self.logoImage.frame.height)
self.logoText.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - self.logoText.frame.width/2, self.logoText.frame.origin.y, self.logoText.frame.width, self.logoText.frame.height)
self.usernameTextField.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - adjustedViewWidth/2, self.usernameTextField.frame.origin.y, adjustedViewWidth, self.usernameTextField.frame.height)
self.passwordTextField.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - adjustedViewWidth/2, self.passwordTextField.frame.origin.y, adjustedViewWidth, self.passwordTextField.frame.height)
self.loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - adjustedViewWidth/2, self.loginButton.frame.origin.y, adjustedViewWidth, self.loginButton.frame.height)
```

Comment: Hi @aashah7, you don't need to add or remove constraints, you can achieve the desired out put buy using the multiplier betweens the views (UIImage,UILabel, UITextfield & UIButton). and changing the height constraint of the scroll view when the keyboard is up. Make sure the constraint of the image view is connected with the top of scroll view and Forgot Password is connected to the bottom of scroll view